# Create mutually exclusive image slideshow (two images shown at same time, cannot ever be same)

Tags: php, sql, slideshow

Thanks for helping in advance.  This is a similar question asked by someone else recently, ([Random Switch Statement Improvements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214561/random-switch-statment-improvements)) but the solutions provided over there did not do the trick for me.

In case you don't feel like going to that page, here's the problem.  I have a 2 slideshow images, one on top of the other.  I want those images to never be the same, either on page load or as the slideshow shuffles through for infinity.

I've tried adding

```
"ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2"
```

and that only made the slideshow images disappear.

Here's the code:

```
$getRugInfo = "SELECT f_name, l_name, city, zipcode, dfd.name as state_id, rug_types, profile_photo, profile_url, prt.rating  FROM rug_owners ps 
left join rug_states pst on dfd.state_id = ps.state_id left join rug_reviews 
prt on dfd.user_id = ps.user_id  WHERE promoted_rug = 1 ORDER BY ";  


$range_values = range(1,6);
shuffle($range_values);
$pickRug=array_pop($range_values);

 // I tried doing the code above, but it did not make the slideshow images mutually exclusive.  THe same two images would show up on occasion.  

$pickRug = mt_rand(1, 5);

switch($pickRug) {
case 1:
    $getSliderInfo .= "f_name";
    break;
case 2:
    $getSliderInfo .= "l_name";
     break;
case 3:
    $getSliderInfo .= "city";
    break;
case 4:
    $getSliderInfo .= "profile_photo";
    break;
case 5:
    $getSliderInfo .= "city DESC";
    break;
}

$sliderResult = mysql_query($getSliderInfo); // calls the slideshow

$link_address = $row["profile_url"];
```

Then it is the same thing as above for the second slideshow image (the image on bottom)

Here is the Jquery to create the slideshow:

```
 <script>
    jQuery('#Slider').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade', 
    speed: 3000
});
    jQuery('#Slider2').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade', 
    speed: 3000
});
</script>
```

Again, it's basically the same problem the other person had in the link provided above, it's just that the solutions provided did not work.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the range of random numbers and adjust the switch statement like below:

```
$pickRug = mt_rand(1, 15);

switch($pickRug) {
    case 1:
    case 4:
    case 7:
        $getSliderInfo .= "f_name";
        break;
    case 2:
    case 5:
    case 8:
        $getSliderInfo .= "l_name";
         break;
    case 3:
    case 6:
    case 9:
        $getSliderInfo .= "city";
        break;
    case 10:
    case 12:
    case 14:
        $getSliderInfo .= "profile_photo";
        break;
    case 11:
    case 13:
    case 15:
        $getSliderInfo .= "city DESC";
        break;
}
```

This jumbling will give you more unique result.

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly Kundan!  I implemented the changes you recommended, and it definitely decreased the problem.  The only problem is that there are only 5-6 users (or rugs in this case) that meet the criteria (paying to be promoted on the homepage).  So what I really need is something like "if user 1 is on top, user 1 cannot be on bottom, move to next user).  Hope that makes sense, that's what I mean by "mutually exclusive"

Comment: @user3577545, i understand your concern so i think you could store the current slider info like it number or name in a variable or session and each time check the next generated number and if its equal to the previous one than run that random method again.